# js audio slider for video not responding to any input

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I'm new to coding and have no idea what I'm doing. This is my js for a very simple audio slider next to a video.

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    var video = document.getElementById('video1');
    var volumecontrol = document.getElementById('volume1');
    var setVolume = function() {
        video.volume = this.value / 100;
    };
    volumecontrol.addEventListener('change',setVolume);
    volumecontrol.addEventListener('input',setVolume);
</script>
```

Here is the relevant HTML code.

```
<div class="video">
        <video controls autoplay muted loop id="video1"><source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>
<div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" oninput="setVolume(this.value)" onchange="setVolume(this.value)" min="1" max="100" value="1" step="1" class="slider" id="volume1"></div>
```

The error I get in the console looks like this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
> at volumecontrol.addEventListener('change',setVolume);

Help pls...

Comment: this refers to the global object. What is the value of this.value?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't really know what I'm doing, I've just been copying random bits of code hoping it works out. Should I have a number instead of "this.value"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LMAO.
Okay.
I had the `muted` tag on the video active. Lol...
Disregard my stupidity, thank you.

I added the following code to allow for autoplayed-muted.

```
var unmute = function() {
        video.muted = false;
    }
volumecontrol.addEventListener('change',unmute);
volumecontrol.addEventListener('input',unmute);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your `<script> </script>` inside the `<head> </head>` tag, Because if the script loaded before the html, `document.getElementById('volume1')` will be null

[Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54171545/how-to-fix-cannot-read-property-addeventlistener-of-null-error#54171598)

Comment: No, I've put it in the body at the end of the document.